# How to create an array of pointers to structs? C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct

I wrote this piece of code that I am not sure exactly how it works, but it works. This is the code:

```
  struct node
{
    string data;
    node *chain;
};

   int tablesize=10;

  node *ptr [tablesize];

  for (i=0; i<tablesize; i++)
{
    ptr[i]=new node;
    ptr[i]->data="Empty";
    ptr[i]->chain=NULL;
}
```

If I understand it correctly, first I create an array of 10 pointers, then I assign each pointer with a new node? Why does it work only when I dereference it twice though? 
(                      ptr[i]->data="Empty";)

Comment: Because `ptr[i]` is a pointer. You are not de-referencing twice. BTW you are using variable length arrays (VLAs), which are not standard C++.

Comment: Don't forget to clean up your mess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `ptr` is declared as an array of pointers. Thus `ptr[i]` is a pointer to node. Hence you need to dereference it in order to access the pointed to entitiy.

Comment: So is it right to say that  node *ptr [tablesize]; is actually pointer to pointer array?

Comment: @Reboot_87 no, it is an array of pointers to `node`. Just like `int a[10]` is an array of ints.

Comment: I think it is because: node *ptr [tablesize]; is the same as writing: node **ptr=new node *[tablesize];

Answer (score 0):

`ptr[i]` is a `node*` therefore you have to use `->`

(you are not de-referencing)

Comment: No? What would you call it, then?